# RPM `requires` installation order

Tags: linux, installation, centos, rpm

I'm seeking for help from RPM experts.

Suppose I have an RPM package `A` which depends on package `B`.
RPM `A`'s spec has `Requires:B` with `autoprov` and `autoreq` enabled.

When I install RPM `A` on a centos 6.5 machine with `RPM version 4.8.0`,
`yum install A` :

- rpm installs `A` first, then it installs `B`.
- The installation of `B` could partially fail. That is, `A` would installed even if the installation of the dependency, `B` has failed.

Is this the expected behaviour? (Shouldn't `B` be installed before `A`?)

Can the same behaviour be expected across versions (such as el5)?

I was hoping that the dependencies would be installed **before** the main package is installed. 
Which would prevent the installation of the main package, If one of the dependencies failed to install.

Is there any other means to accomplish my requirement?

Thanks.

Comment: Should I be asking this question in `unix.stackexchange` rather

Answer (score 3):

`Requires` say that you need this dependency for runtime. E.g if you put `Requires` in `firefox.spec`, then you will have this dependency installed when user run `/usr/bin/firefox`.

If you need it available during rpm scriptlet execution then you need to state in which phase you need it. E.g:

```
Requires(pre): perl
```

If you need it in several sections you need to list it several times. E.g:

```
Requires(pre): perl
Requires(preun): perl
```

For more information see http://rpm.org/api/4.4.2.2/tsort.html

Comment: Thanks. My only concern is portability across versions. Is there anything that I should be aware of

Comment: I tried this, and the dependent `rpm` B's installation failed, despite this the installation of `A` was successful. (I was hoping that the whole transaction would fail)

Comment: looks like this url is 404.  try this one.  http://rpm5.org/docs/api/tsort.html